# SwitchMap returning nothing in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a `SwitchMap` problem and I can't fix it. I have a set of category buttons and when clicked, the page makes a server call and loads it. However sometimes if I click fast and switch between tabs, I get wrong results. I tried this method, but I am not getting any result at all. I am not sure how to use `SwitchMap` in this case.

**component**

```js
GetCustomers(CategoryId) {

  const searchInput$ = new Rx.Subject();

  searchInput$.switchMap(() => this._customerservice.GetCustomersByFilter(CategoryId).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  err => { },
  () => { })
}
```

**template**

```html
<ion-segment-button value="{{item.CategoryId}}" 
  (ionSelect)="GetCustomers(item.CategoryId)" 
  *ngFor="let item of SubCategories">
     <h6 
        {{item.CategoryName}}
     </h6>
</ion-segment-button>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the connection between the html and the ts. However, switchmap should return an observable, you are returning a subscription.

Comment: If you are not doing anything in the error and completed functions you can leave them out, they are optional

Comment: I updated the question. On click I am calling get customers function

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is quite strange:

```
const searchInput$ = new Rx.Subject();
```

No one pushes value inside `searchInput$` subject, so your code inside

```
searchInput$.switchMap(() => ...your code here... )
```

will be never get called.

Maybe you missed some significant details in your example?

Comment: Yh I am a little confused. How can I achieve the switchMap in this case

Comment: Why you need switch map? If you want just to send a request to the server all you need is: this._customerservice.GetCustomersByFilter(CategoryId).subscribe( () => {....})

Comment: Yes, But when I click the category buttons fast, I am getting wrong results because multiple services are being called at the same time and I am getting wrong results.

Comment: Seems they were called by some other reason. Not because of your switch Map. Put "debugger" keyword right inside of your searchInput$.switchMap( () => { debugger }).subscribe( () => {} ) and you will see that it was never get called. Most probably your code works in a different way than you describe.

Comment: No what I mean, I have multiple buttons each represent a category. They all call the same function. When I click 2 3 buttons consecutively, one result may arrive earlier. I want to show the result of the last click

Comment: Ok. 1) create categoryChanged$ in constructor and call categoryChanged$.next(newCategoryId); in click handler 2) in constuctor write: categoryChanged$.switchMap( (category) => { return sendRequest$() }).subscribe( (response) => { updeteValueInUI() }); 3) Optional use debounce(300) downstream to categoryChanged$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150926/discussion-between-artem-and-missak-boyajian).